# SSRS 2008 R2 Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am relatively new to SSRS 2008 r2. I would like to know if it is possible to set up a subscription that would generate multiple .pdfs (to multiple people) by filtering on a unique ID. For example, suppose I want to send a report to Bob Johnson, John Doe, and Richard Nixon and have the column headers (such as address, phone number, etc) be the same but with their unique data values. Is this possible? And if so, how would I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [data-driven subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with a "Data-Driven" subscription, which unfortunately requires the Enterprise version of SQL Server.  I will need to defer to someone who has experience with that version.
If we're talking less than 5 subscriptions, then do them individually and either hard code or pull their contact info for each subscription.  It's not ideal, but it works.